# Postfix suddenly hostname (MX) not found error, now can't send emails, recieve just fine

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

A few days ago I could send emails just fine. Now all the sudden I can not send emails. I just get the error below:

> Jan 27 05:25:14 frontier postfix/smtp[22428]: C291A6801DF: to=<*@*.org>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=*.org type=MX: Host not found, try again)

Something about MX. I can get emails just fine.

Comment: `to=@.org`: Is this really the message or did you modify that? If you did, try to check for the MX record of the target domain: `host -a <targetdomain>`

Comment: I removed the email address for privacy reasons.

Comment: So again: Try `host -a <targetdomain>`and look if there is an MX record displayed. `<targetdomain>`means the domain that is mentioned in `Name service error for name=<targetdomain> type=MX: Host not found`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to put the results in a code box.  nate@frontier:~$ host -a gmail.com
Trying "gmail.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28405
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.   IN ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.  299 IN A 216.58.193.101
gmail.com.  299 IN AAAA 2607:f8b0:400a:801::2005
gmail.com.  3599 IN MX 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you can reach dns and receive replies properly. Make sure you don't have two separate dns servers in your config that are not exact duplicates or it can cause issues of inaccurate dns lookups. If none of this, I would check if your dns provider changed MX records at all.

Comment: My DNS looks good.  Here's a picture of my DNS settings.  https://goo.gl/photos/T2BL6sWo18NX2AJ99  I had not made any changes  to the computer that postfix runs on.  I only have one DNS setting and that is the router.  So the DNS is 192.168.0.1 and the router DNS is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: What if you are on the server and do dig commands on the addresses? Do they resolve to the same ips that you have configured? It may be configured correctly, but is that truely how they resolve according to the server's point of view?

Comment: DNS listed as 127.0.1.1 Should be 192.168.0.1 Network manager doing the connection with manual address with DNS of 192.168.0.1 nate@frontier:~$ dig gmail.com
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> gmail.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26990
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.  17 IN A 216.58.193.101

;; Query time: 69 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)

Comment: I had an old entry in interfaces.  It was commented out.  It was #dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8  I removed it completely and rebooted the computer.  Presto, several days worth of emails showed up that were from my email server.  Dunno why a commented entry would have made a difference.  I do have bind9 installed as a recursive DNS.  But I have not used it.  My interfaces file is now the default on as shipped by Ubuntu 16.10.  It's all network manager now.  Clarification would be helpful.  Appreciated.